# how to convert a python string to a list acording to spaces

Tags: python, list, scripting

how would I write this:

```
string = 'hello world'
string = something
string
[hello, world]
```

please note that im a beginner and will aperciate a noob friendly explantions :)

Comment: You should learn about `split` built-in function.

Comment: `string = string.split()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` string method to split a string based on a given delimiter. Omitting a delimiter splits the string on any whitespace.

```
>>> string = 'hello \t\n  world'
>>> string
'hello \t\n  world'
>>> split_string = string.split()
>>> split_string
['hello', 'world']
>>> more_string = 'hello<NEWWORD>world'
>>> split_more = more_string.split('<NEWWORD>')
>>> split_more
['hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. It returns a list of words in a string that are separated by the delimiter that you passed in as the parameter.

```
result = 'hello world'.split(' ')
result
['hello', 'world']
```